# How to integrate bootstrap in the client side web part using spfx angular?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap, spfx

I'm new to development and also to Spfx. I'm making use of pnp- spfx generator to create client side web part using Angular. I need to use bootstrap for styling the controls. 
Bootstrap is working fine with Angular elements(ng serve) but not reflecting in Spfx webpart.
Can anyone let me know how to integrate bootstrap with spfx using Angular.

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Please post your attempted code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE: Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help:)

Comment: It is not recommended to use bootstrap in Office 365, you can use Office UI Fabric that it is integrated with Office 365 and it has a good documentation: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/